# How to implement drag and zoom for text on canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas

Added some text to canvas as follows ,how to implement drag functionality and zoom functionality for text on canvas.Here is my code to add some text on canvas

```
public class Test extends Activity {
  ImageView drawingImageView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
        .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // Custom Font Text

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setTextSize(40);
    Typeface chops = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
        "WC_Speed_Bold_Bta.ttf");
    paint.setTypeface(chops);
    float text_x = 120;
    float text_y = 120;
    canvas.drawText("Hello", text_x, text_y, paint);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To zoom add

```
canvas.scale(scalefactor, scalefactor);
```

here scalefactor will be the scale value(like scalefactor= 1.5f) by which you want to zoom your canvas.

Comment: I don't want to zoom my canvas